# Creating and Managing Sessions using Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, server

How can I create sessions and manage them in Node.js without a framework like express?

I know it would be much easier to use express but I want to know how to do it with node just in case.

Most of the questions that mentions managing sessions in node is using express to do so but I want to know how to do that without express.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple starting point, suppose we starts sessions when a user login and destroy when he logout.

So when a user login, we basically create a unique session-id and store this session-id at some db like redis/mysql at our server, same will be given to client for next subsequent requests. (Note do not store session-id in memory of the server, as if the server restart we will loss this sessions)

So next time whenever a new request come from the client with session-id we will identify the user and serve response on the basis of that session-id.

Whenever user logout, we remove the session-id from our db. Similarly we can add timeout for the session-id.

This is a simple concept, it can be extended as required.

Comment: Do you think I want to know what sessions are or how they work?
My question is specific and clear. I am asking about how they are created and managed using node. If you can help or have any resources that may help please add them here. Thanks for your understanding!